# Swagger.json - Required properties in definitions not working because of mustache-file

Tags: json, swagger, mustache

I'm trying to mark some properties of a definition in a Swagger.json as required. The syntax I tried sadly doesn't work out.

EDIT: The situation is, that after generating the API all the fields have a questionmark after their name marking them as optional.

```js
"definitions": {
    "Kasse": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "numberA",
        "numberB"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "numberA": {
          "type": "integer"          
        },
        "numberB": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "additionalInfo": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Additional Info for Kasse",
          "example": "Hi this is additional Info."
        }
      }
    }
```

EDIT: What I additionally found is that a file called "model.mustache" out of a custom-template that goes by the name "typescript-angular2" is responsible for the questionmarks that are placed right after the name-placeholder. See this little code example.

```js
{{#vars}}

{{#description}}
    /**
     * {{{description}}}
     */
{{/description}}
    {{name}}?: {{#isEnum}}{{classname}}.{{{datatypeWithEnum}}}{{/isEnum}}{{^isEnum}}{{{datatype}}}{{/isEnum}};
{{/vars}}
```

What I now need to know: Is this custom template just not optimal / can I edit it without further problems?

Comment: Your syntax is correct. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Thanks @Helen. After generation of the Apis all the fields are marked with a questionmark right after the name. I found that this is due to some custom-templating.
The custom-template that is used during generation is the one called "typescript-angular2". There is a file called model.mustache and this file has a questionmark after the "name"-placeholder.
I updated my orignal post to include these findings.